# HashMap computeIfAbsent's lambda execution

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a method that uses a lock to protect a HashMap. With the lock, the method calls computeIfAbsent then releases the lock. I have a unit test that uses a cyclic barrier to create thread pressure to call my method and exercise the lock. Most test runs run fine, but sometimes it fails. This leads me to believe that even though the call to computeIfAbsent is protected by the lock, the running/completion of the F (lambda) provided to it is not.

I wanted to confirm this suspicion or learn of techniques how I can confirm this suspicion on my own.

```
public class Example {
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    HashMap<String, Integer> idAssignments = new HashMap<>();
    List<Integer> returnedIds = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer maxId = 0;

    public getAssignedId(String name) {
        lock.lock();
        Integer assignedId = idAssignments.computeIfAbsent(name, generateId);
        lock.unlock()
        return assignedId;
    }
    public generateId(){
        if(returnedIds.size() > 0) {
            return returnedIds.get(returnedIds.size() - 1);
        } else {
            return ++maxId;
        }
    }
}

public class ExampleTest {

    public testGetAssignedId() {
        CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(500);
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(500);
        HashSet<Integer> receviedIds = new HashSet<>();
        String[] names = new String[] {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            poolOf500Threads.submit(() -> {
                barrier.await();
                Integer assignedId = example.getAssignedId(names[i % 5]);
                receviedIds.add(assignedId);
                latch.countDown()
            });
        }
        latch.await();
        assert(receviedIds.size() == 5)  <--- sometimes equals 6
    }
}
```

My test has a hashset to track all the values returned by my method. My test *sometimes* sees more unique values returned than the unique keys I call the method with. Could the threads be safely *calling* computeIfAbsent but because a prior call to `integerProducingMethod` has not stored in the map yet then some following thread calls `integerProducingMethod` for the same key as the prior?

Comment: The snippet you posted looks fine to me. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: This code looks ok. Your test might be the culprit.

Comment: Your hypothesis would make sense if not for the lock.  The lock means any storage to the map should be _done_ before anything else can touch the map.

Comment: @shmosel  added a reproducible example!

Comment: @BurakSerdar indeed, I added my test in case there is something wrong with it

Comment: There are a bunch of compile errors.

Comment: Protect `receviedIds.add(assignedId)` with a lock.

Comment: @BurakSerdar thanks, are you thinking that there could be a duplicate entry of the same value in the HashSet?

Comment: No, I'm thinking because of concurrent writes you have a corrupt hashset.